# TreeView and HieracrhicalDataTemplate from single class

Tags: wpf, treeview

I've got a class:

```
class WorkOrder
{
    public string Building {get; set;}
    public string Area {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    List<Item> Items {get; set;}
}
```

I'm currently sorting like this:

```
-Name
    -Item
    -Item
-Name
    -Item
    -Item
```

with xaml like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WorkOrder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name} Margin="5,0" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Item}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I'd like to sort this in a TreeView like:

```
Building
    -Area
        -Name
        -Name
    -Area
        -Name
        -Name
```

Not sure if I should be looking at MultiBinding or somewhere else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any way to do it with just bindings or XAML. I had a play under the assumption that you do not want to change your WorkOrder or Item classes (because if you wanted/were allowed to change them, you could just make in another layer in your object hierarchy).

As a UI side workaround you could do something like the following:

1) Add a class that holds the grouping information for a building

```
public class BuildingGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WorkOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

2) Create a converter to transform your current collection of work orders into a collection of building groups

```
public class GroupingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var workOrders = (IEnumerable<WorkOrder>)value;

        return GroupTheseBadBoysByBuilding(workOrders);
    }

    private IEnumerable GroupTheseBadBoysByBuilding(IEnumerable<WorkOrder> workOrders)
    {
        var buildingGroups = workOrders.GroupBy(w => w.Building);

        foreach (var buildingGroup in buildingGroups)
        {
            yield return new BuildingGroup
            {
                Name = buildingGroup.Key,
                Orders = buildingGroup,
            };
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

3) Set up a data template for the building group

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BuildingGroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

4) Create an instance of the converter and use it on your treeview

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders,Converter={StaticResource testConverter}}" />
```

I think the only major caveat with this approach is that you will lose any INotifyCollectionChanged handling (no idea if you were using it or not!)

Comment: Thanks that works.  I was not using INotifyCollectionChanged the binding is one time one way.